# Clicking on two or more different Angular (ng-click) buttons with same function and same class on IE

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, download

I need to download files from a web platform that uses JS. I need to use VBA to do it from an Excel file. So far I have had only one file per URL, so it was pretty easy to do the macro for this, however, recently I have had more than one file per URL and I need to download all of the files.

The instruction/code I use for the download is the following:

```
IE.Document.querySelector("[ng-click*=downloadFile]").Click
```

It works perfectly when it's only one file.

However, I do not know how to download the subsequent files (could be 1, 2 or even 3 more). The partial code from the website looks like this, can't disclose more, sorry!:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="file in folderInfo.Files">
<td>
<a class="linkUnderlined linkHand ng-binding" ng-click="downloadFile(file.Id)">202001_Company_DK_Arrivals.xlsx
</a>
</td>
<td class="ng-binding">14-Feb-2020</td>
</tr>

<!-- end ngRepeat: file in folderInfo.Files -->

<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="file in folderInfo.Files">
<td>
<a class="linkUnderlined linkHand ng-binding" ng-click="downloadFile(file.Id)">Confirmation Company Danmark AS 202001 A.pdf
</a>
</td>
<td class="ng-binding">14-Feb-2020</td>
</tr>
```

What can I do to download both files, given that the function of the ng-click is the same as well as the class?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll()` to get a list of elements and then loop each item in the list.

Comment: you will need a for loop that run for i = 0 to IE.Document.querySelectorAll("[ng-click*=downloadFile]").Length - 1 ; and then index into that to get .item(i) during loop

Comment: Thanks to @KostasK. and @QHarr! I got the inspiration with the querySelectorAll() and now it works :)